# popToRootViewControllerAnimated does nothing, cannot get app top go to home sceen

Tags: ios

I cannot get the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to work (Cannot get any of my apps to return back to home screen) .  I tried creating a new blank test project and it still did not work, thus is what I did:

A. Used the wizard to create a single vue app

B. Added a `UIViewController` class through Xcode (add new file) called `cHome`

C. Added a button on the main storyboard

D. Added a Action for this by dragging and dropping called it a test

E. On the generated methed I added the following code:

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    if (mHome == nil)
    {
        mHome = [[cHome  alloc] initWithNibName:@"cHome" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController: mHome animated:NO];
}
```

G. I added a button to `attest.xib`

H. Added the `- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender;` to header and used UI to link it to button

I. Added following code to `attest.m`

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

J. put a break point on code

K. when I run app, press button on first screen then button on next screen, breakpoint goes off, but app does not go back to pre screen
code

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cHome.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    cHome *mHome;
}
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender {
    if ( mHome==nil)
    {
        mHome = [[   cHome  alloc]
                initWithNibName:@"cHome"
                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController: mHome animated:NO];

}
```

**cHome.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface cHome : UIViewController
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender;
@end
```

**cHome.m**

```
#import "cHome.h"

@implementation cHome

- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}    

@end
```

Comment: I removed some effectively dead code. Please reduce your problems to make them more readable and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the view controller was presented modally, you need to *dismiss* it, not pop to root, which would be appropriate if you had pushed the controller:

So replace this block of code:

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

with this:

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Alternately, if you wanted to pop the view controller, you would have to push it first. So, make sure that `ViewController` is the root view controller of a `UINaviagionController` in your storyboard, then update the code as follows:

```
// In `ViewController.m`
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    if (mHome == nil)
    {
        mHome = [[cHome  alloc] initWithNibName:@"cHome" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mHome animated:YES];
}

// In cHome.m
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering my quastion but i get a error saying "Unexpecting  type name BOOL..."

Comment: Thank you for the help, ok [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; goes back one view on the stack but not to the home view, how could I go to the home view when using ModalViewController? Currently all my xcode 4 code will not go to the root screen in xcode 5 becouse the code i was using [ mHomeController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
    [mHomeController.view addSubview:mHomeController->adView];
 will not compile says addview does not exist,

Answer (score 0):

if you use navigation control as a root view control in app delegate then this is enough to go home view

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```